# webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch with fixed divs

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

I've this small issue, I've created an HTML5 website with ASP.NET where the header is fixed, but on iPad and iPhone it scroll really slow so I had to use this small code in my CSS:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

The scroll issue is gone but the fixed header doesn't work anymore on apple products. But on Windows and Android it works like a charm.

Also I had an autoplay video that plays when its visible and now it doesn't  work anymore on any device.

My code:

```
<style>
body, html, form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
#wr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#header .fixed-menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
#header .menu {
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
```

Please help (and sorry for my bad English)

Comment: hello @Hamaody could you post a sample of the html you are using?